# application context file get changed while building using pom

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have application-context.xml file for spring batch job which uses property placeholder to read value from database.properties.

I am using pom file to build the tar.gz file.

I build and unzip it on unix machine. then after checking application context file its place holder value get changed to maven url.

Following is happening.

before build :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url"
                    value="${url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" /></bean>
```

which get changed by following after doing maven install:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url"
                    value="http://maven.apache.org" />
            <property name="username" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
 </bean>
```

There is 'url' variable declared in pom file which url value which get replaced. Does variable in pom will change it's value in application -context file? why pom will read/edit application context file?

Can anyone faced same problem? Thank for help.

Comment: I suspect that you have declared in the pom that ${} or {} indicate tokens that need to be replaced by Maven during its copy. You would be better showing the pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering the file with maven.

When filtering, maven will replace placeholders in the file just like it does in the POM. This is very useful if you want to dynamically assign values.

In your case the placeholders maven uses are the same as those used by Spring so you have several options:

1) Escape the placeholders, as [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
          <escapeString>\</escapeString>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
```

And then in the file you would have `\${}`

2) Change maven's [delimiters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#delimiters)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
          <delimiters>
            <delimiters>@</delimiters>
          </delimiters>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
```

This would fix your issue but if you rely on filtering elsewhere you would need to change those files.

3) Disable filtering as [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). This may be the easiest solution but may break things too.

Comment: Thank you. I checked my pom file it includes other descriptor.xml file which has this filtering statement. But instead changing anything other, I have commented url tag in pom.xml.It was very informative as I am new in pom.

Answer (score 1):

This is called resource filtering. It is done by the maven-resources-plugin and can be switched off in the POM.

See the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, URL was changed by filtering "maven-resources-plugin" :
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Some other plugins also support filtering, check pom.xml.